# The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, razor-3

Just clicked on new Razor v3 Website in visual studio 2017 v15.4.3 and tried to run it.  It's kicking out the following error: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.ConnectorInstaller.  Ive search web.config and every other file in the site and I dont have any references to MySql nor did I add any refs to it.  I do have MySql installed on my dev machine, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Package Manager reinstall WebMatrix.WebData

```
update-package WebMatrix.WebData -reinstall
```

Restart VS